# fatal error: sys/eventfd.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, nanomsg

I try to build nanomsg for Android

```
~/work/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build
```

and I have error:

```
In file included from /home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/utils/efd.c:28:0:
/home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/utils/efd_eventfd.inc:27:25: fatal error: sys/eventfd.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/eventfd.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/home/roman/work/Nano/app/obj/local/armeabi/objs/nano/src/utils/efd.o] Error 1
```

But I see bionic contains this file (see [here](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/sys/eventfd.h)).

I can't understand what is wrong!
I use this Android.mk: https://gist.github.com/kristianlm/27d12ca7e4b2ef8e89fc

Can anybody help me with it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added Application.mk and it works:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS:= -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.8
APP_PLATFORM := android-10
APP_ABI := armeabi
```